# What's the difference between a Banach Algebra and a C*-algebra?

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, operator-algebras, banach-algebras

I'm currently looking at going into a PhD program in mathematics and need to decide on a specialization. In meeting with my advisor he pushed me into looking at C*-algebras based on my interests. However specialists in the field seem to be rather rare and in expanding my search it seems that Banach Algebra's are closely related but I'm not entirely sure on the distinction (other than C*-algebras seem to be a specific form of Banach's). Can someone tell me the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is true: $C^*$-algebras are a special class of Banach algebras. But they have a very rich
structure as they appear as selfadjoint algebras of operators on a complex Hilbert space.
The theory of $C^*$-algebras is very developt. On the other hand, general Banach algebras are
a much wider class of algebras and working on them one has to assume some additional conditions. Actually any Banach space can be made in a Banach algebra by a trivial multiplication, or by a multiplication given by $x.y=\xi(x)y$, where $\xi$ is a fixed bounded linear functional on the space... In any case, for working on $C^*$-algebras, one has to know the general theory of Banach algebras and, on the other hand, working in general Banach algebras, one has to be familiar with $C^*$-algebras as they are a very important class of Banach algebras.

Comment: If I remember correctly, self adjoint operators on Hilbert spaces are valued because of their use in manipulating quantum systems without Hamiltonians. Are Banach Algebra's useful in any way to solve similar systems?

Comment: Of course Banach algebras are useful in modern theories in physiscs. Selfadjoint operators are useful in classical theories. But since during the last decades many new phenomena have been discovered, people working on those things are looking for mathematical structures which are more general and can describe those new phenomena. For instance, in last 15-20 years a lot of work has been done on Banach algebras where the multiplication is not associative - also on algebras of this tzpe which are analogs of $C^*$-algebras. This area of mathematics is very alive.

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: @user218075: Note that Hamiltonians *are* selfadjoint operators. Quantum systems without Hamiltonians can appear for example large thermodynamical systems. There one is naturally lead to consider von Neumann's approach to quantum mechanics. What one ends up is then abstract C*-algebras. But that is still before Banach algebras.